# UITextView not populated with default text when app has been updated

Tags: ios, core-data, uitextfield, uitextview

The premise of my app is simple. The user enters in some information into textFields and textViews and when saved, the TableView is populated with that information (with a combination of Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController).

In version 1 of my app, the "add entry" screen has only UITextFields and no UITextViews. In version 1.1 of my App, I have brought a UITextView for notes. The default text is "Additional Notes: " and this is set in the Storyboard.

**Problem**

What I'm seeing is, if I create an entry in version 1 and then update my app to version 1.1 from Xcode, the existing entries, when you click on them in the UITableView do not display the word "Additional Notes :" in the UITextView until I actually click on the UITextView cell in which case, my shouldBegin method gets called and it displays it. That is undesirable though because users who upgrade should see the word "Additional Notes: " in the UITextView for existing entries. Essentially Additional Notes is a "placeholder" so if you don't enter in any notes, you should always see those words.

I've set the text in the UITextView in Storyboard but nothing seems to be working.

I have two different view controllers for creating a new entry and editing an entry in Storyboard (because of some slight adjustments) and if you add a new entry, it shows the word Additional Notes :". If you add a new entry but didn't put in any notes, when you edit it, you'll still see the word Additional Notes:. However, entries added from version 1 of the app do not show the word "Additional Notes: " when it comes to editing the entry and I cannot understand why this is the case.

Here are my two main methods:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    if([[textView text] isEqualToString:@"Additional Notes: "]){
        [textView setText:@"Additional Notes:\n"];
    }
    return YES;

}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    if([[[textView text] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""]){
        [textView setText:@"Additional Notes: "];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

So I know I'm missing something, but why can't users who have upgraded, have existing entries displaying the word Additional Notes: in the UITextView without having to click on it.

Any guidance would really be appreciated.

Comment: You should confirm and re-check that text is set in both controllers's textviews.

Comment: @zaheer I've checked and it looks like it's set 100% correctly in both controller's textViews in Storyboard Inspector for the textView. Should I be setting something in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - not really, that was just a quote to help understand the question. I want the "default" text of the UITextView to be set for existing entries from upgrading from a previous version of the app

Comment: Ok, One more check, check whether the textview's text is being changed in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace the txt message text in your textview text name,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [txtmessage setText:@"Additional Notes:"];
[txtmessage setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

}


- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    if(txtmessage.text.length == 0){
        txtmessage.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        txtmessage.text = @"Additional Notes:";
        [txtmessage resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO;
}

if(textView.text.length >=65)
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];

    return NO;

}
if([text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]].location == NSNotFound) {
    return YES;

}

[textView resignFirstResponder];
return NO;

return YES;
}

- (BOOL) textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
if (txtmessage.textColor == [UIColor lightGrayColor]) {
    txtmessage.text = @"";
    txtmessage.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

return YES;
}

-(void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
if(txtmessage.text.length == 0){
    txtmessage.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    txtmessage.text = @"Additional Notes:";
    [txtmessage resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this answer is not suitable for u, may be it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used a slight adjustment of the code and made sure to put an if condition in the viewWillAappear. This works great. Thanks again